# How to iterate a json array nullsafe?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `json` array that I want to iterate as follows:

```
offer.products.forEach(function(product) {
   console.log(product);
});
```

Problem: if `products` list is null or empty or undefined, this will produce an error.

**Question**: how is safe iterations done properly in javascript?

Comment: Some relevant reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
(offer.products || []).forEach(function(product) {
   console.log(product);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the fitting checks:

```
if (offer.products) { //blocks products==null and products==undefined
    offer.products.forEach(function(product) {
        console.log(product);
    });
}
```

Empty should not be a problem, since forEach should not do anything if products is empty.